# Cannot upload the data to firebase database with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Flutter and Firebase and cannot seems the two works with each other. I'm not getting any error messages or crashes it just not uploads the data to the database.

Here's the code:

```
Future<DatabaseReference> savePost(Post post) async {
  
  ref.child('posts').push();

  var data = post.toJson();
  await ref.set(data);
  return ref;
}
```

Here's where I call it:

```
  void newPost(String text) async {
    var post = Post(text, widget.user.displayName);
    setState(() {
      posts.add(post);
    });
    post.setId(await savePost(post));
  }
```

Also set the rules in firebase to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true, 
    ".write": true, 
  }
}
```

Tested with postman and it uploads nicely with the following url syntax:
https://PROJECT-ID-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/.json
tried to pass the url to the database ref method but the code fails nicely

Comment: It was an interesting problem, but I just leave it here if anybody has the same problem. I don't know what caused the error, probably I just set up the plugins or connection SDK in the beginning. So what I did just followed the instructions when I had to add firebase to the project, re-added the google-services.json also, and rebuilded the project and it worked.